# Laravel 5.2 Auth not sending cookie

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

td;dr: I am sending a JSON response to the auth-request but the session-cookie is missing.

I am using a login method similar to the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` one. In my case the response it sent in JSON format and no view is rendered. Here is the controller code:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $guard = 'web';

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

        if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
        if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            Auth::user()->incrementLoginCounter();
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }

        if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Its basically the same thing as the Trait from Laravel.

**The Problem:** There is no cookie getting sent with the response.

**Here is what i know:**

- the remember_token column of the user table in the database is getting set correctly
- i can set cookies manually with `response()-> ... ->cookie('name', 'value')`
- the manually set cookies are sent in the response correctly
- the guard driver is set to `session`, the provider is set to the `App\User` class
- the session driver is `file` and config is the default laravel config
- the web middleware is the same as default, Csrf-Middleware is turned off on that endpoint.

**What I'm hoping for:** Best case - a solution for the issue, or any tipps and ideas on what i could test to figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem myself and it was a rather odd thing. What I did was to open the laravel repository on github and go through all the App-files that would be loaded on the request and compared them to my local version. That means Router, Controllers, Middlewares, Providers etc.

The RouteServiceProvider was missing a whole method. That lead to the app telling me that the web middleware was applied when it actually wasn't.

Maybe this was because the previous developer updated Laravel to the latest version and didn't do the job right. Maybe it was some Git merge that messed it up.

The point is - sometimes its good to just go through all the files line by line and compare it to a working version :)